# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I am using Android Studio and when I try to rebuild it builds properly but while running I get the following error, I am using Twitterkit plugin in the project

```
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I am not able to understand where the error is and I am stuck for a very long time,I am sorry if it is a duplicate question but I tried looking up for existing solutions for the problem but no luck so far :(
Any suggestions will be really helpful

My build.gradle is as below

```
  buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "schooltalk.com.playschoolpublisher"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
        compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.4@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.5.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug

Comment: Check the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32202153/4576879) . It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `multidex:true` don't forget to make an `Application` class in your project that extends from the `MultiDexApplication` or a lot of bad stuff will happen

```
public class YourApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    ..........
}
```

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: I have added this in androidmenifest.xml actually I added the both based on one SO answer but no luck with it

Comment: I never tried with manifest, but I have got it working like I suggested.  Also I have found a good blog here http://androidhumanrobot.blogspot.in/2015/05/multidex-issue-in-android-development.html?m=1